# cshtml files not serving from subdirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

First off, I apologise if this question has actually been answered previously, but I cannot find a valid response.

I have created a very basic web SITE in Visual Studio 2013, not an application or MVC or anything like that.

The default file is `default.cshtml`

1) When I run in debug mode, no problem
2) When I publish to my IIS 7 server's wwwroot folder, `http://webserver/default.cshtml` works
3) When I publish to a subfolder of wwwroot, `http://webserver/folder/default.cshtml` gives a "This type of page is not served." error message

I know the server CAN successfully serve up the `.cshtml` type files do to #2 above.

So what am I missing that it will not serve up `.cshtml` from a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

`cshtml` files are served up by MVC routing, not by direct URL referencing. IIS does not know what to do with a `cshtml` file.

Basically you can only use that file type in a routed web app and not a basic website.

In MVC the URL would be `http://webserver/somecontroller` or `http://webserver/` and the routing would choose which `cshtml` files to run and output.

The actual `cshtml` file rendered is selected implicitly based on the controller name, the action name (method run on the controller), what the action returns, and also any route mappings.

Comment: TrueBlueAussie, Thanks for your response. I understand the concept of the MVC structure and how controllers work, what is baffling me is that if I publish to the ROOT folder of my site, all works as expected. Its only when I move the files to a sub-folder that I get the error. Grrrrr

Comment: I am surprised that it even allowed a `cshtml` to load from the root. That may have been a side-effect of something else (a default mapping to default.cshtml in the root?)#